# What is the global Virasoro symmetry generators in BTZ spacetime?

Tags: black-holes, symmetry, conformal-field-theory, ads-cft, holographic-principle

[image]

This is the case of AdS3, how about BTZ? The picture is from [arxiv:1506.01353](http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.01353).

Comment: What attempts have you made at the problem and what were your results?

Comment: As is well known, Virasoro algebra in 2D CFT has its generators defined by radial quantization,through mapping from cylinder to Riemann surface.  I tried to do the coordinate transformation from complex coordinate to polar coordinate,but I failed, it seems that I misunderstand something, so I cannot get (4) in the picture.What's more, I want to get the symmtry generators in BTZ spacetime just like those in (4), but I don't know how to do, so I come here and ask the question.